# angular 2 validation based on other field value?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

Im trying validate the form field value based on the other field so i have written a custom validator when i tried to get the value other field it throws error i have tried the following code kindly help me thanks in advance

```
   export class CreatesessionComponent implements OnInit {

      eventform : FormGroup ;

     constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

       }


      ngOnInit() {

       this.eventform = this.formBuilder.group({
          eventname : new FormControl(''[Validators.required,Validators.pattern('[A-Za-z]+')]), 
          userlive : new FormControl('',[Validators.required,this.maxuser]),
          totaluser :new FormControl('',[Validators.required,this.totaluser])

       });
      }

totaluser(control : FormGroup) : {[s:string ]: boolean} {
  console.log(control.controls['eventname'].value)
//  if(control.value > 20){
//    return { total : true };
//  }
return null;
}
```

gives error in the console as cannot read the property of 'eventname' undefined

Comment: `eventname` is in the form gruop called `this.eventForm` not in the form controls that you're passing.

Comment: so i need to pass this.eventform to the totaluser() ??

Comment: nop, you just need to use as follows: `this.eventForm.get('eventname').value`.

Comment: when i use this.eventForm.get('eventname').value inside the totaluser function it says Property 'eventForm' does not exist

Comment: Strange. Did you missed to add `eventForm: Formgroup;` in your class?

Comment: yes i have added see my updated question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am currently doing something like this also. In order to get it to work I get the group for the control and then search that group for the required control

```
totaluser(control : AbstractControl) : {[s:string ]: boolean} {
  const group = control.parent;
  if (group) {
    console.log(group.controls['eventname'].value)
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: it seems that the validator runs more than one time, also when the field is being initialized, so I got the error: `Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined`. So, need to verify that parent is not undefined first, and later validate.

Comment: This is not working when the value of `eventname` changes. It will only validate when the value of this form control i.e. `totaluser ` changes